# Why is the keydown key code 32 greater than the keyup one?

Tags: javascript

I made a simple [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6066f8s/) that listens for key down and up events:

```
window.document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
    return false;
});

window.document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
    return false;
});
```

When I press down on a letter, the key code logged is 32 greater than the key code logged while pressing up. Why is that?

Comment: Because key handling (as opposed to an actual *letter* being typed) in JavaScript is .. fun. Basically mapped from *arbitrary virtual key codes* (who defined these back in the day?). YMMV; the values are just what they are.

Comment: I think it is fairly arbitrary. Somebody way back when in like the 1900s (gasp) just decided that the up arrow should be before the down arrow.

Comment: @jsve The question is not about the ordering. If you press on a key, and then depress that same key, 2 different key codes are logged.

Comment: Keyup is case insensitive. Keypress is case sensitive. Also explained and demonstrated here - http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/12/20/jquery-difference-between-keypress-and-keydown-events/

Comment: @tmrlvi wow. thats rediculous.

Comment: Are you talking about `which`, `charCode`, `code`, `keyCode`, ...? Detecting keys in JS is a mess. And the `keypress` event is deprecated.

Comment: @Oriol where have you read that the `keypress` event is deprecated?

Comment: @NormanBreau [DOM L3 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-keypress): "*The `keypress` event type is defined in this specification for reference and completeness, but this specification [deprecates](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#glossary-deprecates) the use of this event type.*"

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges. The `keydown` and `keyup` events are triggered by pressing and releasing keys. The code reported represents the key. The `keypress` event is triggered when pressing or holding a key (repeating) results in a character input. The code reported represents the character.